# Android: Slide Images

Tags: android

How to slide images by finger in Android ? I mean like Gallery app slide photos...
And how to do that animation if I want to slide photos by clicking on button ? Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For the animation, see [ImageSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html)
- For the gesture part, see [this tutorial](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847)

Comment: So if I want to slide one image to another by clicking "next" button...I should use Image switcher ???

Comment: Can you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950831/android-imageswitcher ? Thanks..